# pf - time of day filter

Tags: pf

I'm using pf: https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/config.html, as a firewall on my router.  I would like to implement a time of day filter in pf if that is possible so that I wouldn't need to script it myself via a cron job.

In iptables and nftables, there is such a construct that I can find; however, I don't seem to see one with pf.  Is that possible, if so, where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to check the source for opnsense and from the few minutes I looked, it appears to be using cron:

https://github.com/opnsense/core/blob/master/src/etc/inc/plugins.inc.d/pf.inc#L50

pf.inc:

```
function pf_cron()
{
    global $config;

    $jobs = array();

    if (isset($config['filter']['rule'])) {
        foreach ($config['filter']['rule'] as $rule) {
            if (empty($rule['disabled']) && !empty($rule['sched'])) {
                $jobs[]['autocron'] = array('/usr/bin/logger "reload filter for configured schedules" ; /usr/local/etc/rc.filter_configure', '1,16,31,46');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, as I confirmed my suspicions, I will use cron too :(.

Comment: Although unrelated, squid provides a time of day filter.